# HTML not responsive to larger screen resolutions

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on a site for a client, and something really odd is happening. You can find the current site here http://107.170.219.136

The site looks and works find on my screen resolution (1920x1080), but it appears that for larger resolutions the banner and banner text doesn't respond to the screen size. When I tested the site on a screen resolution of 2560x1440 it appears like the following:

[2560x1440](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y4wm.jpg)

Although, a tester is reporting the same issue with the same screen resolution as I. I've been searching for possible solutions like adding a media break point to my CSS and setting the banner to `max-wdith: 100%;` but nothing. Here's the banner HTML piece of the site:

HTML

```
<div id="banner">
    <img src="assets/sd-home.jpeg">
    <div id="bannerText">
        <h1>San Diego’s First Choice for Bankruptcy Relief</h1>
    <div class="banner_sep">&nbsp;</div>
```

and the full CSS

```
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #a4a4a4;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color: #a4a4a4;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: #a4a4a4;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color: #a4a4a4;  
}
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.clearfix{
    clear: both;
}
.wraper{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.maincontainer{
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.topbar_bg{
    padding: 12px 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
.topbar{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.logo{
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #3b97d3;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    max-width: 26%;
    width: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.logo span{
    color: #3a3a3a;
}
.logo span.lg_fl{
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: none;
}
.logo span.lg_cm{
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.topbar_rght{
    max-width: 542px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}
.location{
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 46%;
    width: 100%;
}
.location a{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.location a .icon_location{
    max-width: 48px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
.location a p{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 18px;
}
.phone{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 47%;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}
.phone a{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.phone a .icon_phone{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    float: left;
    max-width: 32px;
    width: 100%;
}
.phone a p{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.phone a h4{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #3b97d3;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.video{
    padding: 150px 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #eaeaea;
}

#banner{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%
}



#bannerText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 4vw;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;

}

.banner_sep{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.section2{
    padding: 60px 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: url(../images/texture.jpg) repeat;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #eaeaea;
}
.section2_content{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.section2_lft{
    max-width: 480px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.section2_rght{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 490px;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
}
.section2_heading{
    padding: 0;
    /*margin: 22px 0 10px 40px;*/
    margin: 22px auto 10px auto;
    /*max-width: 245px;*/
    width: 100%;
}
.section2_head_lft{
    float: left;
    height: 1px;
    background: #3b97d3;
    max-width: 220px;
    width: 100%;
}
.section2_head_mdle{
    float: left;
    max-width: 23px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -22px 0 0 12px;
}
.section2_head_rght{
    float: right;
    height: 1px;
    background: #3b97d3;
    max-width: 220px;
    width: 100%;
}
.section2_lft p{
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 25px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #595959;
}
.section2_lft h3{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #595959;
}
.section2_lft h2{
    font-size: 36px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #3a3a3a;
}
.form_bg{
    padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border: 5px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    max-width: 450px;
    width: 100%;
}
.form_heading{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
.form_heading h1{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 3px 0 0 0;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    text-align:left;
}
.fields{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:440px; 
    width: 100%;
}
.form-control{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.input_field{
    padding: 11px 3%;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 94%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #a4a4a4;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

}
.frm_lft{
    max-width: 48%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 4% 0 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.frm_rght{
    max-width: 48%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}
.select_field{
    padding: 12px 3%;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #a4a4a4;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

}
.textarea{
    padding: 11px 3%;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 94%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #a4a4a4;
    min-height: 80px;
    height: auto;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.btn_sbmit{
    padding: 28px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #3b97d3;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #245977;
}
.btn_sbmit:hover{
    background: #318ac5;
}
.frm_lines{
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}
.help_bg{
    padding: 60px 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.help_content{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.help_heading{
    max-width: 560px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    font-size: 48px;
}
.heading_icon{
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 245px;
    width: 100%;
}
.help_head_lft{
    float: left;
    height: 1px;
    background: #3b97d3;
    max-width: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.help_head_mdle{
    float: left;
    max-width: 23px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -36px 0 0 12px;
}
.help_head_rght{
    float: right;
    height: 1px;
    background: #3b97d3;
    max-width: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.chapters{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 100px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.chapter_colm{
    padding: 0 19px 20px 19px;
    margin: 0 2% 0 0;
    max-width: 280px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #dedede;
    border-radius: 10px;
    min-height: 490px;
}
.chapter_colm:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #cecece;
}
.chapter_icon{
    padding: 12px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 120px;
    border: 2px solid #3b97d3;
    border-radius: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
.chapter_colm h3{
    padding: 25px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    text-align:center;
}
.chapter_colm h2{
    padding: 25px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.chapter_colm p{
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #595959;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 22px;
}
.chapter_line{
    max-width: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 4px;
    background: #3b97d3;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
@media screen and (min-width:850px) {
.chapter_colm_mrg, .chapter_colm:nth-child(3n+3){
    margin-right: 0;
}
.chapter_colm:nth-child(3n+4){
    clear:both;
}
}
.help_option{
    padding: 40px 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.help_colm{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 2% 0 0;
    max-width: 32%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
@media screen and (min-width:850px) {
.help_colm_mrg, .help_colm:nth-child(3n+3){
    margin-right: 0;
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}
.help_colm:nth-child(3n+4){
    clear:both;
}
}
.help_colm_lft{
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 24%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #3b97d3;
}
.help_colm_rght{
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    /*max-width: 100%;*/
    width: 100%;
}
.help_colm_rght h4{
    color: #3b97d3;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.help_colm_rght h3{
    color: #3a3a3a;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.help_colm_rght p{
    color: #767676;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 24px;
}
.grey_bg{
    padding: 50px 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #3a3a3a;
    width: 100%;
}
.btns{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.btn_green{
    max-width: 470px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.btn_green a{
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 12px 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #72b12f;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #507f19;
}
.btn_green a span{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
}
.btn_green a:hover{
    background: #68a527;
}
.btn_blue{
    max-width: 470px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}
.btn_blue a{
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 25px 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #3b97d3;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #245977;
}
.btn_blue a:hover{
    background: #358ec8;
}
.footer_bg{
    padding: 30px 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
.footer{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}
.footer_lft{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    /*max-width: 33%;
    width: 100%;*/
}
.footer_lft ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.footer_lft ul li{
    padding: 0 8px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
.footer_lft ul li:last-child{
    border-right: none;
}
.footer_lft ul li a{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.footer_lft ul li a:hover{
    color: #b5afaf;
}
.footer_rght{
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.error{
    text-align: left!important;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
}
.thankyou {
    padding: 35px 20px 50px 20px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border: 5px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    max-width: 450px;
    width: 100%;
}
.thankyou_heading{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.thankyou_heading h1{
    font-size: 48px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}
.thankyou p {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #595959;
    text-align: center;
}
.thankyou{
    display: none;
}
.icon-icon_judge{
    font-size: 78px;
    color: #3a3a3a;
}
.icon-icon_lawer{
    font-size: 78px;
    color: #3a3a3a;
}
.icon-icon_weight{
    font-size: 78px;
    color: #3a3a3a;
}
.btn_green2{
    max-width: 470px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 52px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.btn_green2 a{
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 11px 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #72b12f;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #507f19;
}
.btn_green2 a span{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
}
.btn_green2 a:hover{
    background: #68a527;
}
```

I'm fairly new to responsive design so any advice is much appreciated. I just want the site to appear the same way it appears for me, and hopefully for you as well.

Comment: too me it looks like the image just isn't big enough. If you want it to always be full widht you'd have to set width: 100%, not max-width: 100%

Comment: I didn't examine everything. However, media queries should be placed **after** all other CSS, not in the middle. That way they are implemented *last*. That may be your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `img { max-width: 100%; }` CSS on your page. That will only allow the image to grow up until 100% of it's max width, then will not expand further. That's great as a general rule for images on your site, but not great if you want the image to exceed it's native width for super wide screens. If you add this CSS, that image should scale to larger screens `#banner > img { width: 100%; }`

Comment: Awesome! This worked. But it messed up the banner text making it so that it doesn't stay inside of the image, but still scales down. Any suggestions?

Comment: @salce not sure what you mean - it looks like this to me http://i.imgur.com/MJJqJXq.jpg. Is that not what it looks like to you, or is that not how it's supposed to look?

Comment: Here's how it is for me http://imgur.com/a/APBRK and then for mobile the text scales down, but doesn't overlay the image and just stays at the top and covers the logo http://imgur.com/a/lfdRY thanks for help

Comment: @salce have you made other changes? what browser and OS are you using? that's not what it looks like for me on mobile, either. http://i.imgur.com/OoX5WA0.png

Comment: Sorry, I didn't push to dev. You can view the updated site here http://107.170.219.136/ you can see that when you resize the window the banner text positioning isn't responsive. I was playing around with the `top` property but couldn't achieve the result I need.

Comment: @salce add `position: relative;` to `#banner`